# Conversion of array to tif_Expected array of dim 2

Tags: pyqgis, digital-image-processing, array

I'm trying to perform a simple operation on an image, which is applying a median filter to it (for now). I'm trying to do it with QGIS and the console Python. My code is :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import gdal
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdalconst import *


#Image reading
rasterpath = r"//sites.fr/DVR/RHONE-ALPES/RCA/Traitement_PTHR3D/PFE/Caroline GRUSSI - 2020/Données Test/Tunnel Croix Rousse - Lyon/2018_gris.tif"
ds = gdal.Open(rasterpath)
band1 = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

#computation
im_med = ndimage.median_filter(band1, 3)

#ouput image creation
cols = ds.RasterXSize
rows = ds.RasterYSize
in_band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
outRaster = driver.Create("//sites.fr/DVR/RHONE-ALPES/RCA/Traitement_PTHR3D/PFE/Caroline GRUSSI - 2020/Données Test/Tunnel Croix Rousse - Lyon/2018_mediane.tif", cols, rows, 1, in_band.DataType)
outRaster.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())
outRaster.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())
outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
outband.WriteArray(im_med)
```

The error message i'm getting is "ValueError : expected array of dim 2".
So I checked, and wrote

```
im_med.shape
```

To which the response is " () ". So dimension zero ?
Does anyone has an idea about what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What is `type(im_med)` ?

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to fix the problem by replacing "band1 = ds.GetRasterBand(1)" by `band1 = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())`